# Backticks make <link> tag to function improperly

Tags: backticks, quotation-marks

Why `` <link rel = `stylesheet` href = `css/styles.css`/> `` does not work but `<link rel = "stylesheet" href = "css/styles.css"/>` does? Aren't backticks interchangeable with quotation marks?

Comment: No. You can use either single-quotes (also known as apostrophes), i.e. `'`, or double-quotes, i.e. `"`. Backticks are not recognized as quotes in HTML. However, you *can* use backticks in Javascript.

Comment: Absolutely, thanks a bunch! That's awesome.